# Proper way to create composite PK

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key

As far as i know, there are 2 ways of creating a composite PK, but dont know the differences or which is the good one:

```
CREATE TABLE AppUsers
(
Id int NOT NULL,
Username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(100),
FirstName varchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY (Id, Username)
)
```

VS

```
CREATE TABLE AppUsers
(
Id int NOT NULL,
Username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(100),
FirstName varchar(100),
CONSTRAINT pk_AppUsers PRIMARY KEY (Id, Username)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Specifications:*

According to this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html and this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html, the `CONSTRAINT` key word is optional for a `PRIMARY KEY`.

*Best practice:*

I would say, use the one whichever you prefer regarding to readability. I'd tend to limit the extra letters though, similarly to using `JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Absolutely right, just realized after posted the question. Besides that, i also find out that using CONSTRAINT keyword will make your code to run on SQL server and Oracle aswell (just in case someone is interested in using the same schema through different DBMS's)

Comment: I think oracle accepts the primary key also without the constraint word

Comment: The CONSTRAINT syntax allows you to control the name of the constraint.  This can be useful when an error message includes the name of a violated constraint.  It can also be useful if you browse the metadata (very rarely done).

Comment: Thanks @WalterMitty. What about this in the context of a primary key? Could you name it? I thought the name of the primary key was always "PRIMARY"

Comment: I'm not sure.  I think the DBMS assigns some kind of name to it.  The name is indicative of the table in question as well as indicating a primary key constraint.  If that name is good enough, then my previous comment is moot.